# Rails: FasterCSV - Unique Occurrences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I have my CSV file imported as such:

```
records = FasterCSV.read(path, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)
```

How can I get the **unique occurrences** of my data?  For instance, here some sample data:

```
ID,Timestamp
test,2008.12.03.20.26.32
test,2008.12.03.20.26.38
test,2008.12.03.20.26.41
test,2008.12.03.20.26.42
test,2008.12.03.20.26.43
test,2008.12.03.20.26.44
cnn,2008.12.03.20.30.37
cnn,2008.12.03.20.30.49
```

If I simply call `records[:id]`, I just get:

```
testtesttesttesttesttestcnncnn
```

I would like to get this:

```
testcnn
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is not **masive** you can use the [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) class.

Here's an example:

```
p ['cnn','test','test','test','test','cnn','cnn'].to_set.to_a
=> ["cnn", "test"]
```

Here's a simple benchmark:

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm(5) do |x|
  x.report("Set")   do
    a = []
    20_000.times do |i|
      a << 'cnn'<< 'test'
    end
    a.to_set.to_a
  end
end

=>
           user     system      total        real

Set    0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.109000)
```

Comment: How massive are we talking?  My CSV file will have on average 2000 entries; is that too big?